# apache virtualhost redirection on ubuntu 14

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I had set up 2 domain virtualhost files under /etc/apache2/sites-available,

```
www.example.com.conf
example.com.conf
```

apart from the default configurations. 
I've been trying to create a redirection from example.com to www.example.com and it doesn't seem to work,
I don't know where I'm going wrong.

In **www.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project
</VirtualHost>
```

In **example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mailzak.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

After adding them, I had configured with "a2ensite" and restarted Apache. But the redirection doesn't work.

Comment: They had to, your config seems okay. Is apache restart really worked? Try to stop apache, check for any remaining apache process, kill them if they exist, and then restart.

Comment: Another tip: could you doublecheck, if in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled , _both_ of the soft links to the virtualhosts are existing and they are pointing to the correct file?

Comment: Have you verified that (1) the request to example.com is arriving at your server (check /var/log/apache2/access.log), and (2) the VirtualHosts are enabled (try `apachectl fullstatus` and search the result for `VirtualHost`)?

Comment: @Peter.. I see the same links on sites-enabled and linked correctly.

Comment: This isn't a problem actually, and leaving out the fact that redirecting non www to www shouldn't be handled this way, it's about 2 websites with the same root and it depends on which loads first, try renaming the redirect vhost by adding an a in front (example.conf becomes aexample.conf) re enable and reload apache2 service ...

Answer (score 0):

Provided that www is a canonical alias of the naked domain, you don't really need two .conf files.

You only need one .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/project
</VirtualHost>
```

Which can be activated with `a2ensite example.com`.

Then create an .htaccess file in /var/www/project

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: mod_rewrite for a redirect?